# Partition-based model in R

Tags: r, partitioning

Im predicting readmission to the hospital, every health specialty has its own rules and has its own feature importance. I need to create a model which would basically split and every specialty would have its own model with its own feature importance and I could even tune the parameters separately per group. 
Currently I did just a few specialties and tried to combine in a loop but very clunky. Is there a better way? Also, how to evaluate such a model?

Thanks

Comment: So then what is common between those specialties? Sounds like you simply want separate models and that's all. In that case, a loop can be fine. Currently the question is too broad and it's hard to say anything about "better ways" without seeing any code.

Comment: Specialties, for example, Cardiology, Neurology etc. Its just a part of the whole system. if I do a loop it won't run in parallel. But yeah, I might just stick to a loop. Thanks